# is noun or verb comes after "IS"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-choice

I wrote the following sentence, but I am not sure whether "is modification" should be changed to "is modifying."

In such cases, what word should be placed after *is*? Is there any rule?

> The best solution *is modification* of the graph, for example, {1,2,1,3,4,5,4,6,1} into {1,2,3,5,4,6,1} by utilizing the concave cover along the outer border.

Comment: Since you use it a lot, I feel I should point out that "I am having the following construction" is not proper English. "I have the following construction/sentence" is correct, but you'd be even better off with "I wrote the following sentence:". We don't say *I am having* when we possess something, we say *I have*. *I am having* is only used for things like *I am having tea* (which doesn't mean I *possess* the tea, it means I am currently drinking it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is acceptable. *Modifying* in this context is a "gerund", the *-ing* form of the verb acting as a noun. The only difference is that a "gerund" acts simultaneously as a verb and takes objects, so you don't need the preposition *of*:

> The best solution is modifying the graph ...

You may also employ the marked infinitive *to modify* in the same way:

> The best solution is to modify the graph.

FOR [LAGNIAPPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagniappe):
In all these instances your "for example" needs work.

1. The following phrase should have its own verb—the implied construction "modify X into Y" is not idiomatic.
2. It should be set off with something stronger than a comma. I don't know enough about what you're discussing to be sure how the last pieces are related, but one or the other of these should be right:

   > ... graph; for example, transforming {1,2,1,3,4,5,4,6,1} into {1,2,3,5,4,6,1} by utilizing the concave cover along the outer border. -*This assumes that the **transformation** is accomplished by utilizing the cover*.
   >
   > ... graph (for example, by transforming {1,2,1,3,4,5,4,6,1} into {1,2,3,5,4,6,1}) by utilizing the concave cover along the outer border. -*This assumes that the **graph** is modified by utilizing the cover*. If this is the case you would do better to set the parenthetical example after the "utilizing" clause.

Comment: thanks, yes it is, that mean at the end of the sentence, the parenthetical example should be placed.

Comment: +1 for *lagniappe* - I never knew *that* word before. :-)

Comment: Would "is a modification" sound more natural for an English native speaker than "is modification"?

Comment: @Stephen *A* modification would be appropriate only if there is only one applicable way of modifying the graph.

Answer (score 2):

If you use 'modifying' you should remove the following 'of'.

> The best solution is modification of the graph

and

> The best solution is modifying the graph

are both grammatically correct. I'd suggest the second one sounds a little better, though.

There isn't a rule that makes one of them wrong.